# Column level Encryption/Decryption is not working after copying data from one database to another database and restored keys and certificates

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have copied encrypted tables data (on column level) from database A to database B within the same server and followed below steps while creating and restoring keys and certificates, but column level decryption is not working in Database B.
Eg: In Database A, table name is "employee" and encrypted column name is "emp_id_proof". Now I have created the same "employee" table copy in database B from database A within the same server and restored certificates and keys in new databases but I am not able to decrypt "emp_id_proof" column data in Database B.

**1) Steps to create master key, certificate and symmetric key in database A**

```
USE DatabaseA    
go    

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MyStrongPWD@2022'    
go
 
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate_test WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect my data'    
go

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey01 WITH
   KEY_SOURCE = 'SymKey01KeySource',
   ALGORITHM = AES_256 ,
   IDENTITY_VALUE = 'SymKey01IdentityValue'
   ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test    
go
```

**2) Steps for backup of master key and certificate in database A**

```
USE DatabaseA    
go    

BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportMasterkey'  
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD =  'abc@2022'    
go    

BACKUP CERTIFICATE Certificate_test TO FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportCert'
   WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportCertPK' ,
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xyz@2022' )    
go
```

**3) Steps for restoration/creation of master key,certificate and symmetric key in Database B**

```
USE DatabaseB    
go    

RESTORE MASTER KEY  
    FROM FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportMasterkey'  
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'abc@2022'  
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MyStrongPWD@2022'    
go    

CREATE CERTIFICATE [Certificate_test]      
   FROM FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportCert'    
   WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ENCRYPTION\ExportCertPK',
   DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xyz@2022')    
go    

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey01 WITH
   KEY_SOURCE = 'SymKey01KeySource',
   ALGORITHM = AES_256 ,
   IDENTITY_VALUE = 'SymKey01IdentityValue'
   ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test      
go
```

Could you please let me know what went wrong??
Also let me know the steps if I have to copy encrypted columns data from one server to another server database.

Comment: Are the two databases on the same server and/or same SQL Server version? _SQL Server 2016 uses the SHA1 hashing algorithm for its encryption work. Starting in SQL Server 2017, SHA2 is used instead. This means extra steps might be necessary to have your SQL Server 2017 installation decrypt items that were encrypted by SQL Server 2016._ Ref: [Encryption changes in SQL Server 2017 CU2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-identical-symmetric-keys-on-two-servers#encryption-changes-in-sql-server-2017-cu2)

Comment: Both databases are on same server. I am trying different options to implement Encryption for our SQL Server database column. There is a table with a varbinary(max) column which is storing binary data of images, pdf documents, etc. This data should be encrypted at database end, when we try to fetch the data from UI we should see decrypted data..